# Creating a custom language highlight in Komodo Edit 7

Tags: syntax-highlighting, komodoedit

I have been searching around for a while, and was wondering: is there an easy way to create a new custom language in Komodo Edit 7?

To clarify what I mean, check out the easy-and-simple-to-use UDL for [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages)

I easily created a syntax highlighter for a custom language that I use for my work/study (it's basically a cut-down subset of Java).  Npp allowed me to use both a GUI and to edit the .udl easily to do this.

Is there a similar way to do this in Komodo?  The only article I can find is from 2007 and relates to Komodo 4: [ActiveState Community Article](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2007/01/adding-new-languages-komodo-udl)

Is this the only method? I don't need it to be a full blown extension and I certainly do not want to add intellisense: I just want it to highlight keywords, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [macro if it's a tag-based language](http://community.activestate.com/forum/highlighting-matching-tags). For other languages, find the path to [keywords.py](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/silvercity/PySilverCity/SilverCity/Keywords.py), choose a supported language with similar elements, then replace its keywords with your own. Restart Komodo, open a file of that type, then update the [color preferences](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#colors) and [use a macro to debug](http://community.activestate.com/faq/debug-udl-language-styling) your changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for a reply - I had thought nobody would ever say something!  Those links look really helpful, so you have my thanks, and my tick!